# Calculating an effect of intervention on two groups with very different values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, anova, t-test, mean

Imagine I run a marketing campaign in two cities with very different number of citizens (like A: 1000 and B: 1000 000).

Purchases_A and Purchases_B define the number of products sold in each city:

```
month     Purchases_A Purchases_B Campaign 
January   100         100 000         0
February  120         150 000         0
March     90          70 000          0
April     100         100 000         0
May       80          120 000         0
June      90          110 000         0
July      120         80 000          0
August    180         220 000         1
September 200         300 000         1
October   190         220 000         1
November  180         200 000         1
December  180         220 000         1
```

The campaign was launched in July. I need to test if the average effect
of the campaign was greater in one of the cities, but the numbers of both variables are very different. Is it ok to conduct a Min-Max-Scaling on both Purchases_A and Purchases_B and then conduct the t-test or Mann–Whitney U test on the variables Purchases_A and Purchases_B in range <0-1> or is there a better approach to solve this problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is actual data from a marketing campaign, you don't need statistics to show that there is a bigger increase in purchases after July in the larger city. A scatterplot of the data illustrates this convincingly. (The interpretation on the other hand might require some nuance: after all, the larger the city, the more potential customers for any kind of product. In other words, why not do the campaign in the larger city only?)

With so many even numbers, however, it's unlikely this is real-world data. So let's estimate the *proportional* campaign effect in each city. First, divide by the population size to normalize the monthly purchases: *y = purchases / population*. Now the outcome variable *y* (purchases per person) is comparable between cities.

(At least) One challenge remains: it's not reasonable to make the equal variance assumption: since the scale of the business is different, we expect more variability in purchases in the larger city and, as a result, higher variance in *y* also. This expectation holds true for the provided data. (I'll ignore other potential challenges — for example, seasonality in demand — and let you think about them instead.)

So let's use regression (which generalizes the t-test) but allow the variance of *y* to differ by city. I fit this regression using Generalized Least Squares (GLS); the R code is attached at the end. Both visually and statistically, the campaign has a bigger effect in city *B*.

```r
model <- gls(
  y ~ city * campaign,
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | city),
  data = campaign
)

emmeans(model, ~ city | campaign)
#> campaign = 0:
#>  city emmean      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  A     0.100 0.00496 10   0.0890    0.111
#>  B     0.104 0.01210 10   0.0773    0.131
#> 
#> campaign = 1:
#>  city emmean      SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>  A     0.186 0.00587 10   0.1729    0.199
#>  B     0.232 0.01432 10   0.2001    0.264
#> 
#> Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95
```

[image]

---

Here is the R code to reproduce the analysis and the figure.

```r
library("nlme")
library("emmeans")
library("tidyverse")

campaign <- tibble::tribble(
  ~month, ~Purchases_A, ~Purchases_B, ~campaign,
  "January", 100L, 100000L, 0L,
  "February", 120L, 150000L, 0L,
  "March", 90L, 70000L, 0L,
  "April", 100L, 100000L, 0L,
  "May", 80L, 120000L, 0L,
  "June", 90L, 110000L, 0L,
  "July", 120L, 80000L, 0L,
  "August", 180L, 220000L, 1L,
  "September", 200L, 300000L, 1L,
  "October", 190L, 220000L, 1L,
  "November", 180L, 200000L, 1L,
  "December", 180L, 220000L, 1L
)

population <- setNames(c(1000L, 1000000L), c("A", "B"))

campaign <- campaign %>%
  rename(
    A = Purchases_A,
    B = Purchases_B
  ) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    c(A, B),
    names_to = "city",
    values_to = "purchases"
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    campaign = as.character(campaign),
    month = factor(month, levels = month.name, labels = month.abb, ordered = TRUE),
    population = population[city],
    y = purchases / population
  )

model <- gls(
  y ~ city * campaign,
  weights = varIdent(form = ~ 1 | city),
  data = campaign
)

emmeans(model, ~ city | campaign)

campaign$.fitted <- predict(model)

campaign %>%
  ggplot(
    aes(month, purchases / population, group = city)
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      color = city,
      shape = campaign
    ),
    size = 2,
    stroke = 1
  ) +
  geom_line(
    aes(month, .fitted,
      group = interaction(city, campaign),
      color = city
    ),
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    data = campaign
  ) +
  scale_shape_manual(
    values = c(1, 8)
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.title.x = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! I believe it does the trick in this case. However, do you think it's possible to apply this solution if we don't know the size of each city population - only the sales values that allow us to estimate the top level (max) of sales in each city?

Comment: No, you can't really use the max sales in this way -- you'll lose the interpretability of `y` as purchases per person. And even more importantly, the denominator won't be fixed as it's always possible that next-month purchases are the new max.

Comment: Census data is widely available, so I can't see why that information won't be (relatively) straightforward to find.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I'll have to use fixed/random/mixed effects model then as I will need to replicate this case to the problem of different product categories that differ in terms of demand (like product A has an average of 10 purchases per month and B - 100).